# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. trying to create a chat app and tried all possible changes but couldn't solve this error

Tags: android, android-studio, firebaseui

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.2.1] C:\Users\mr.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-ui-3.2.1.aar\d877f4c00adf0a6b18ddef910b3eaa9b\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
>       Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
>           or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
>           or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.firebase.ui" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manifest merger failed, minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 4 declared in library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54869017/manifest-merger-failed-minsdkversion-1-cannot-be-smaller-than-version-4-declare)

Answer (score 2):

Change here your gradle like :

```
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```