# Manifest merger failed, minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 4 declared in library

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-manifest

I'm trying to launch an Android App which was generated with Ionic, but I got an Error:

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller
>   than version 4 declared in library [com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.4]
>   /Users/gediminassukys/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/PhotoView-1.2.4.aar/ffdb107897f674c9e99efaa7549d295e/AndroidManifest.xml
>   as the library might be using APIs not available in 1     Suggestion: use
>   a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 1,      or increase this
>   project's minSdk version to at least 4,       or use
>   tools:overrideLibrary="uk.co.senab.photoview" to force usage (may lead
>   to runtime failures)

Android Studio after this error suggest me this:

> Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 1,        or
>   increase this project's minSdk version to at least 4,         or use
>   tools:overrideLibrary="uk.co.senab.photoview" to force usage (may lead
>   to runtime failures)

Comment: Are you using any PhotoView library if yes try to change the minimum SDK level 10 4

Comment: Yes, I'm. Where can I change it? If I do this in build.gradle `defaultMinSdkVersion=1`, I still get the same error

Comment: Make defaultMinSdkVersion=4 I'll solve your issue if this issue still persists let me know.

Comment: Already did, same error!

Comment: you might want to rebuild project after clearing cache

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the given library you have to set the minimum sdk version supported to 4 . `defaultMinSdkVersion=4`, this will fix the problem you are facing.

Comment: Already did, same error! Maybe it has something to do with that plugin PhotoView? Why error includes it?

Comment: @Gediminas nope i think it's not. Did you change it at your build.gradle file? Because you have to change it in general. If it doesnt work like that, try adding this line : tools:overrideLibrary="uk.co.senab.photoview" .